# How to connect to internet Ubuntu server command line 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, server, internet

Hello guys I'm very new with Ubunu (well linux in general) and I'm trying to to connect to the internet with a AES3000 wireless adapter, I had already setup the whole server(ubnut server 14.04 command-line only) when I installed it on my server a PE2900. I plugged in the adapter t a usb port but now I have no idea if its connect or how I can check or if ts not how to set it up?? could anyone shed some expertise? with me??

Comment: on the server run ping 8.8.8.8 and iwconfig and ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig
```

displays information (IP address, subnet mask, etc.) for all active NICs.

```
ifconfig eth0
```

displays all information for the NIC "eth0".

```
ifconfig -a | grep eth
```

lists all active network adapters.

I think ping is the command to test for full (gateway and DNS) internet connectivity. e.g.

```
ping google.com
```

If all is functioning properly, it'll display Google's IP address, i.e. 173.194.125.41

References:

1. [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)
2. [15 Useful ifconfig Commands](http://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/)